# ytdl-core stopped downloading youtube videos - I get invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, ytdl

I used ytdl-core for downloading youtube videos but now it stopped working after 2 months when I run my app

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (node:vm:94:7)
    at exports.decipherFormats (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\4)youAdderBackendcopy\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\sig.js:116:51)       
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async exports.getInfo (C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\4)youAdderBackendcopy\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:401:17)        
Emitted 'error' event on PassThrough instance at:
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v20.3.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi. I think your problem is related to `ytdl`, not `youtube-api`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new "bug" in the core library, specifically in `sig.js` .
[Here](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/1252) you can find some workarounds, putting the library back into normal operation

Comment: Thank you but now the problem is solved. Thanks bro